# android studio の SDKをコマンドでアップデートしようとすると、エラーになります。

Tags: android-studio

android studio の SDKをコマンドでアップデートしようとすると、下記のようなエラーが出ます。対処方法などご存知でしたらご教授いただけると嬉しいです。

---

[image: エラー画面]

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: おそらく、[これ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150410/failed-to-run-sdkmanager-list-android-sdk-with-java-9)だと思います。最も票数の多い回答を読んでみて下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。

Comment: jdkのバージョンの問題でした。最新版ではエラーになるようです。こちらのモジュールを使用することで、解決しました。
https://adoptopenjdk.net/

jdkのバージョン問題について参考：https://qiita.com/u-tanick/items/bb166929a58a4c20bb88

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/182311

Comment: 解決した場合は、自己回答ができます。